# CodeIgniter global variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using **$data** in all my views  `$this->load->view('my_view', $data);`

I have also autoload a Controller following this guide [Extending Core Controller](http://ericlbarnes.com/develop/extending-the-core-controller-in-codeigniter/)

But I want to make $data global because in `views` there is a sidebar which is constant for whole project and displays info fetched through db in autoloaded controller

Currently I have to manually write $data['todo'] for each and fetch info from autoloaded **model**.

Thank You.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1: Create `MY_Controller` in `application/libraries` with following:

> ```
> class MY_Controller extends Controller {  
>   var $data;      
>   //constructor function              
> }
> ```

2: Replace `Controller` to `MY_Controller` in all your controller files and load views with `$this->data`

> ```
> class Contact extends Controller { //to.. } 
>
> class Contact extends MY_Controller { 
>  $this->load->view('contact_view', $this->data);
> }
> ```

this way you can perform default functions that are applicable for whole site in `MY_Controller` like loading settings.

Comment: If it does not work, then try putting MY_Controller.php info application/core

And if you change the prefix to something, then be sure to change it in config.php @ $config['subclass_prefix']

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem earlier today. I found that an easier way, rather than globals, was to use constants. You can define a constants file that will load from your index.php file:

```
// Include additional constants
$defines_file = 'includes/defines.php';
if (file_exists($defines_file))
{
    require_once($defines_file);
}
```

Then you can add your constants to the `defines.php` file:

```
define(MY_CONSTANT,'my constant info');
```

This  way they will be available in any file throughout the system either directly: `echo MY_CONSTANT;` or you can assign them to variables.

I decided this way would be easier for me as I would only have 1 location to go to when/if I needed to change the constants.

More: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/56981/#280205

Comment: Its good idea and I am already using for all constant values but this is not suitable for me because I am getting the data from db which is different everytime. Using another include script wont let me use inbuilt CI database lib so I had to go this way

Answer (score 1):

I used a helper function to call a global function!

eg.

```
function get_user($userid){
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $query = $CI->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $userid), 1, 0);
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        // Return a object with userdata!
        return $row;
    }
}
```

Now I have access to my userdata everywhere..

Answer (score -1):

Rather than making the view data global, I'd recommend using [HMVC](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC/) to build a module to produce this sidebar view.  HMVC is a nice clean way of coding partial views.

Comment: HVMC is overkill when you're talking about something as simple as partial views.  If you have a partial view that doesn't change much, just load the view into the constant itself: `define('MY_VIEW', $this->load->view('my_view', '', TRUE));` - then simply echo the MY_VIEW constant in your larger view. HVMC adds a lot of baggage for  something as simple as this.

Comment: Where in the code do you load the data needed to render the partial view?