# How to define a site wide variable in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I make the following variables accessible in **all** the views on my site:

```
$site_name = 'My Site';
$author = 'Jake';
$loggedin = (isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])) ? true : false;
```

I am looking for a Codeigniter approach to this, not just putting the above in a file and "including" them repeatedly in each view I load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter global variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527119/codeigniter-global-variable)

Comment: @Andrew Marshall I tried the chosen solution to that answer before posting and it gave me a controller not found error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach#1:**

You can define these variables in a file and include that file in CodeIgniter's index.php (Then you won't need to include it in each view file). Thereafter you can access these variables in all view/controller files. You'll have to declare variable global though whenever you use it. For example in your view:

```
global $site_name;

//--use $site_name
```

**Approach#2:**

Define these variables in a config file (CodeIgniter's default or a custom one). Then you can access these as:

```
$this->config->item('site_name');
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html