# Global variable in codeigniter helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursion, global-variables, helper

im writing a recursive function that finds the children of an array if it has. now i want to know the level that an array enters finding its child. **for an eg**

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fld_id] => 7
        [fld_value] => Color
        [fld_price] => 0.00
        [fld_attribute_id] => 2
        [fld_parent_id] => 5
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fld_id] => 8
                        [fld_value] => Red
                        [fld_price] => 12.00
                        [fld_attribute_id] => 2
                        [fld_parent_id] => 7
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [fld_id] => 10
                                        [fld_value] => light red
                                        [fld_price] => 20.00
                                        [fld_attribute_id] => 2
                                        [fld_parent_id] => 8
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [fld_id] => 11
                                        [fld_value] => dark red
                                        [fld_price] => 4.00
                                        [fld_attribute_id] => 2
                                        [fld_parent_id] => 8
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [fld_id] => 14
                                                        [fld_value] => double_dark
                                                        [fld_price] => 3.00
                                                        [fld_attribute_id] => 2
                                                        [fld_parent_id] => 11
                                                        [children] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [fld_id] => 15
                                                        [fld_value] => single_dark
                                                        [fld_price] => 0.00
                                                        [fld_attribute_id] => 2
                                                        [fld_parent_id] => 11
                                                        [children] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fld_id] => 9
                        [fld_value] => Green
                        [fld_price] => 5.00
                        [fld_attribute_id] => 2
                        [fld_parent_id] => 7
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

and my **recursive function** is below and it is written in codeigniter helper

```
function get_children_by_par_id($parent_id)
{
$children = get_children($parent_id);
$return_value = array();
foreach($children->result() as $result)
{
    $result->children = get_children_by_par_id($result->fld_id);
    $return_value[]= $result;
}
return ($return_value); 
}

function get_children($id){
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->db->where('fld_parent_id',$id);
    return $CI->db->get('tbl_attribute_values');
}
```

now i want to count the depth of the array that how much level does it went inside using the same recursive function i tried to count the level it went inside in the recursive function i.e `get_children_by_par_id($parent_id)`. but due to recursive function count is initialized to its original value. so i need to make a global variable in the helper. so can any one help me here.... or can you give me the best idea to count the depth of the array and yes **the array can go to the n level**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me out [go here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). I did a bit of twist and turns to the code and for further references you can [Visit here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527119/codeigniter-global-variable). you can create a global variable in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable for counting levels in your class, then  use it to count the levels in your function `get_children_by_par_id`.

As you see in the `test_function` you can get the value of the `$count` variable after calling the function, then you must reset it if you need to call the function again.

```
class yourClass extends somthing{
        $count = 0;
        function get_children_by_par_id($parent_id){
           $children = get_children($parent_id);
           $return_value = array();
           foreach($children->result() as $result){
               $result->children = get_children_by_par_id($result->fld_id);
               $this->count++;
               $return_value[]= $result;
           }
           return ($return_value); 
        }

        function get_children($id){
             $CI = get_instance();
             $CI->db->where('fld_parent_id',$id);
             return $CI->db->get('tbl_attribute_values');
        }
        function test_function(){
             $childs = $this->get_children_by_par_id(1);
             $childs_count = $this->count; // get the levels count
             $this->count = 0; //reset the counter
        }

    }
```

Comment: it is not the class its just an helper where we do have only functions nothing else...

Comment: then you need to create a global variable using config file, you can see details here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html

Comment: the function is also called by another loop, so then i want the loop to be initialized by 0 again

Comment: can you tell me where is this recursive function located? and how are you call it ?

Comment: the recursive function is located on helper and im calling it from the view and above i have edited and add how i called the recursive function from view

Comment: why you complex the problem on yourself, you can create a library like the above code, and you can put it in the autoload if you need that, then use it as you can.