# Codeigniter : Dynamic View

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamic, view, controller

can you please tell how to access view components (div ...) from controller in Codeigniter,
the purpose is to load profiles from database and show or hide some components according to the response
and thank you.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the MVC framework.  Read the documentation on views.

Comment: I recommend to handle views in controller: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317115/is-it-ok-to-put-conditional-logic-on-codeigniter-views/17317621#17317621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the variable from the controller into the view, and then determine whether or not to display sections of each profile. As an example:

Controller:

```
 $data['profile'] = $this->my_model->get_profile();

 $this->load->view('profileView', $data);
```

Then, in the view, you can test for values and display sections.

```
<?php if ($profile = "admin"){ ?>
<div id="AdminDiv">
Special Admin Content
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See Adding Dynamic Data to the View,

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/views.html